# fadeIn/fadeOut not working

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, fadein

I am trying to trigger an animation when I click on a link. The animation has 2 components:
- the div containing the link moves down
- the text for the link changes in a smooth animation with a fadein/fadeout

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
<div id='desc'>
    <p class="lead">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam.
        <a class='more'>much more</a>
    </p>Cras elementum ultrices diam. </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#desc{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
```

}

JS:

```
$('.more').click(function() {

$(this).parent().parent().stop().animate({"top": '+50'}, 'slow','easeOutExpo');

    $(this).stop().fadeOut();
    $(this).stop().html('<i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i> Hide</a>');
    $(this).stop().fadeIn(5000);
```

});

However it's not working and I don't get what I did wrong.

Does anyone have the answer? Here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Z24dK/

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**fiddle DEmo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Z24dK/1/)

```
$(this).stop().fadeOut('slow', function () {
    $(this).stop().fadeIn(5000).html('<i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i> Hide</a>');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the `fadeIn` occur as a callback after the `fadeOut` completes.

```
$(this).stop().fadeOut('fast', function(){
    $(this).stop().html('<i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i> Hide</a>');
    $(this).stop().fadeIn(3000);
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Z24dK/2/